# Show if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt{n}}$ is absolute convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt{n}}$ is absolute convergent or divergent

First i subbed numbers in
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt{n}} = \frac{-1}{1+\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}} - \frac{-1}{1+\sqrt{3}}$$

So it's divergent

**1 LIMIT**
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}=0 \quad \text{hence divergent} $$

**2 $a_{n}$ and $a_{n+1}$**
$$ \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}>\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n+1}} $$
$$ \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n+1}}> 0 $$
hence increasing

or 
$$ \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n+1}} =  \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}} $$

$$ \therefore \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}> 0$$ hence decreasing

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\lvert \frac{-1^n}{1+\sqrt{n}}  \right\rvert = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}   \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}   $

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{3}} $$

if this is convergent then the whole thing is absolutely convergent but i don't know how to prove this

---

UPDATE

I got something out for the second part
[image]

Comment: What you tried to do, what you explain is your problem or your issues is absolutely incomprehensible...

Answer (score 3):

There are so many mistakes (and so severe) in your "solution" that it is a superhuman task to discuss them. Your series is convergent, [Leibniz's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) solves the problem in a second. The series is not absolutely convergent by an application of the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) (compare your series with $\sum \frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ which is known to be divergent).

Comment: Obviously i can't use liebniz's test i have to use alternating test

Comment: @Ivan: Leibniz's test *is* another name of the alternating test...

Comment: Is this right though

$$ \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n+1}} =  \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}} $$

$$ \therefore \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}> 0$$ hence decreasing

Comment: @Ivan: You misuse the sign "$\therefore$": you must put it in front of the conclusion, not of the hypothesis (and, in general, very few people use it, better avoid it completely). What you want to say is $\sqrt {n+1} > \sqrt n \Rightarrow \frac 1 {1 + \sqrt n} > \frac 1 {1 + \sqrt {n+1}}$, and this is correct (and necessary in order to use Leibniz's test).

Comment: oh ok so i just did it around the wrong way.... Umm what happens if it's decreasing?

Comment: @Ivan: Being decreasing towards $0$ is what you need in order to use Leibniz's test. Seriously, are you reading what I write? Everything you need is already written above; you just have to put these pieces together.

Comment: @AlexM. NB I fixed a small but major problem in your post. The series is convergent, but not _absolutely_ convergent. I suppose that's what you meant to say anyway ;)

Comment: @AlexR: Thank you for fixing that; yes, that is what I meant, I typed it in a rush. Also, thank you for signalling this edit to me; it displeases me when people correct things silently without the original author's knowledge. What if the author really meant it that way? (Not the case here, though.)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have some errors I think in your writeup. $-1^n$ likely should have parentheses around the $-1$.  It does change the convergence or divergence of this particular series. There is a different treatment for alternating series. But I'll proceed to answer the problem as written.

Second, your first use of $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ ends with a conclusion that the sequence of terms is increasing. But when fractions get *bigger denominators,* they get smaller... So this is a decreasing sequence.

Third, the series diverges by comparison with the $p-$series. If you are not familiar with this, you should look it up. It's a standard thing in most textbooks.

Now your series is not *exactly* a $p-$series, but it behaves like one. To show that it diverges, you can take

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1/\sqrt n} {1/(1+\sqrt n)} $$

to see why. Since this limit is finite and positive, both series behave the same way.

Now if your series is alternating, i.e. the general term contains $(-1)^n,$ then the series converges *conditionally.*  This is because the sequence of the absolute value of terms strictly decreases to zero, while the series with the absolute value of terms diverges (as we mentioned above).

Either way, your series does not converge absolutely! For this to occur, the alternating series and its associated series with the absolute values of terms must BOTH converge.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt{n}}$.

$$ a_{2n}+a_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2n}}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2n+1}} =  \frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n}}{(1+\sqrt{2n})(1+\sqrt{2n+1})}  =  \sqrt{2n} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2n}}-1}{(1+\sqrt{2n})(1+\sqrt{2n+1})} \sim \frac{n^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{4\sqrt{2} } = O\left(\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)$$

Therefore the serie $\sum (a_{2n}+a_{2n+1})$ is convergent and so is the serie $\sum a_n$.

Moreover, $|a_n| \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $ so your serie is **not** absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{1+\sqrt{n}}>\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

**Absolute convergence**

> If
>   $$ \sum \left|a_n\right| =\mbox{convergent}$$
>   Then
>   $$ \sum a_n =\mbox{absolutely convergent}$$
>   Note that an absolutely convergent series is also convergent.

**Conditional convergence**

> If
>   $$ \sum \left|a_n\right| =\mbox{divergent}$$
>   And
>   $$ \sum a_n =\mbox{convergent}$$
>   Then
>   $$ \sum a_n =\mbox{conditionally convergent}$$

So now 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right|=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right|$$
Since
$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}\right|\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right|$$
And
$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}\right| =\frac12\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right|=\mbox{divergent}$$
Then by the comparison test
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}\right|=\mbox{divergent}$$
Now for the following series
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt{n}}$$
Since
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}=0$$
And
$$  \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}} \gt  \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n+1}} $$
Then by the alternating series test
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt{n}} =\mbox{convergent}$$
Putting everything together, we see that
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt{n}} =\mbox{conditionally convergent}$$